# MySQL pull only one row across tables

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables: one that stores blogs and the other that stores images for the blogs. The image table has columns id, blog_id, image_name

Since a blog can have multiple images assigned to it, how can I pull, say, the 5 newest blogs and have 5 entries that aren't duplicates

I've tried:
Selecting from both tables but the result is like this:

id 1 image "a.jpg" - id 1 image "b.jpg" - id 2 image "c.jpg"

WHEN I WANT:

id 1 image "a.jpg" - id 2 image "c.jpg" - id 3 image "d.jpg"

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Please state the columns in each table and the query you're using (the select)

Comment: How do you know something is one of the "five newest blogs". Is there a date field? Or what?

Comment: Please post the query you have tried so far, so that we can be of help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `GROUP BY id` clause at the end of your query. Since you haven't posted your full query I'm not 100% sure about this, but in simple cases it should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a date column :

`SELECT DISTINCT (id) FROM table_name WHERE somecolumn=someans ORDER BY date ASC LIMIT 5`

Otherwise (this might work for you) :

`SELECT DISTINCT (id) FROM table_name WHERE somecolumn=someans ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5`

Comment: That's going to select distinct rows (entire rows which aren't exactly the same). It seems that the question is more about how to select distinct entries from each column.

Comment: @Grampa nope, it will select distinct `id` which is what he wants in his example. He was having a problem with duplicate `id` as far as i can tell

Comment: Except the question is tagged "mysql". To the best of my knowledge and a quick look at the documentation, MySql does not support "distinct (identifier)". It has "all" and it has "distinct" and that's it.